# My css file not showing when i use laravel-blade

Tags: php, css, laravel, laravel-blade

When I use `php artisan serve` my css doesn't show in the website

I tried to use  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('/resources/css/styles.css')}}" />` but still doesn't work for me

Comment: Welcome to SO ... do you have a folder in your project named `public/resources/css`? and in it is `styles.css`?

Comment: @lagbox my styles.css was in resources/css that's why it didn't work, putting it in public folder solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to move your css file **style.css** file in public folder like **public > assets > css > style.css**
and try to this in you blade :-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/css/styles.css')}}" />
```